# How much time for connection and customs in Charlotte?

Tags: air-travel, short-connections, clt

My wife and I are flying back from Jamaica to Dallas through Charlotte with a 1-hour-14-minute connection. Do we have time to make our connection? We've never been to Charlotte.

Comment: We are returning 9/28/18

Comment: While Charlotte is not huge and is easy to navigate between concourses, you would have to clear immigration, get your luggage and then clear customs, making it pretty tight.

Comment: @Giorgio: And then go through security.

Answer (score 0):

If, presumably, American Airlines sold you that flight combination, you have every expectation of making the connection.  If not, they will accommodate you on one of the many CLT-DFW routings available.

American operates out of a single terminal at CLT so you'll never be that far from any gate.

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine but downvoters are absolutely not obliged to explain themselves. It would be nice if they did but ranting about it is completely out of line.

Comment: While it is technically true that American operates out of a single terminal at CLT, stating it like that may give a false impression that their gate area is compact and easy to walk between, when in fact that is not the case. There is one terminal with 5 concourses that are quite spread out. That being said, I've not found CBP to be bad in CLT, so I would expect that the OP will be fine.

Comment: @cbw As opposed to DFW/PHL and technically MIA & LAX.  Since you re-enter between D and E, you equidistant from everything except B.  Either way, AA thinks you can make it which is why the Downvote is wrong and unwarranted.

Comment: The downvote wasn't me!
I see your point, I just want the OP to understand that just because it's one terminal they may not be that close to their gate, that's all.